# Possible Chrome li width render issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout

I have used [**this template**](http://themeforest.net/item/frenzy-responsive-bootstrap-template/full_screen_preview/3464344) , when decide to check this layout in Chrome and found tricky css bug as for me.

Have a look at list in top of the page: **Sign in - Sign up - My account**.
That's how I see this.
[image]

Zoom normal, Chrome version 27.0.1453.116 m, Windows 7

I have played about 30 minutes with this, but still did not found good solution.

Other browsers show this correct, even Safari and IE!

Does someone have any ideas what this could be?

If set width of UL bigger - Chrome will show it correct, but why the hell I should think about width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Chrome does is quite valid, though perhaps unexpected. Adding a rule to prevent wrapping makes it work as you expected in Chrome:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Why do you thinks it's normal? When there is no fixed width it should be expanded.

Comment: When there is no fixed width, expanding horizontally as well as breaking the text into lines is both valid. That decision is left to the implementation.